# Why does only part of the context menu trigger the associated command in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

I have a need to bind context menu items to a list in my view model.  It works and the code is rather simple, but there is one problem that my users won't accept.  You have to click in a certain area of the context menu in order to get the command to trigger.

If you click outside of the darker blue area then the command does not trigger.
[image: Image of the issue]

The XAML is as follows:

```xml
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MyContextMenuItems}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}" Command="{Binding Command}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>                            
</ContextMenu>
```

It appears that the dark blue is the actual MenuItem control, but I need the parent to be the clickable area, I would also prefer that it was all highlighted the same, but I think That that won't be very difficult to figure out once I know the solution to the main issue.

Comment: Have you looked into styles? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates has an in-depth description of the main context menu and the individual menu items.  It could be based on margins, borders, padding... Might need to play with settings to match your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DRapp's comment I figured out the solution to my issue.  The menu item is actually created automatically and I was creating an menu item inside of the one that was created for me.  The solution was to define the `ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle` instead of using the `ContextMenu.ItemTemplate`.  Below is the final XMAL.

```xml
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MyContextMenuItems}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```